# SED - Generate line using some content of other line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, regular-expression, macos

I have some files in a folder

Each file has this structure:

```
...
product: Nike New Awesome Shoe
price: 123
color: black
...
```

I need to accomplish bellow scenario **using single SED command**, in all files using *.txt

Basicly I need to get First word After pattern in a line that Starts with that pattern, and concatenate with "brand: " in a new line.

Select line that starts with (product: )
Get first word after (product: )
Create a new line concatenating brand: with that first word from other line

PS: I dont have the line number, because line number may change file to file.

```
...
product: Nike New Awesome Shoe
brand: Nike
price: 123
color: black
...
```

Comment: You've tagged your question both `linux` and `macos` - do you need this to work on GNU sed or BSD sed (or both)?

Comment: @they its kind of it... markdown files.... i appreciate if you point me to some resources like that. i use Mac Osx

Comment: Do you mind to explain why it hast to be using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can duplicate the match keeping the needed string

```
$ sed '/^product/{p;s/[^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/brand: \1/;}' input_file
...
product: Nike New Awesome Shoe
brand: Nike
price: 123
color: black
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/^product: \([^ ]*\) .*/&\
brand: \1/' file.txt
```

`^product:`  matches the line that begins with **product:**

`\([^ ]*\)` references the word that follows `product:`

`&` inserts the whole match (in this case the whole line), a backslash followed by a line break adds a newline, which begins with `brand:`  followed by the first referenced `\1` word.

Comment: Thanks @fuzzidrawrings.
Sorry to bother you, but can i have some other help here?

I already run is 1800 files, so the next question have to get done apart from the first command:

Now i have to look for some Keywords in title line, and create some other lines like ie:

...
product: Nike New Awesome Shoe
brand: Nike
price: 123
color: black
...

how can i make another line with Shoe word (in this example) adding in 

prodtype: Shoe ???

Comment: If "prodtype" is the last word on the `product` line (as "Shoe" is in your example), you could add a second parenthetical group to match it. So instead of matching the line as `/^product: \([^ ]*\) .*/`, match it as `/^product: \([^ ]*\).*\ \([^ ]*\)/` then add `\nprodtype: \2` to the substitution. i.e.:
**`sed 's/^product: \([^ ]*\).*\ \([^ ]*\)/&\nbrand: \1\nprodtype: \2/' file.txt`**

Comment: In fact I could not express myself here, what i need is to create new line, only if certain term/string appears in product line...independent of the position. I asked a new question and i will mention you ther. If you could help me ill be glad

Comment: The question correctly made: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697158/sed-generate-line-only-if-match-some-words-in-other-line @fuzzydrawrings

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is a YAML file:

```bsh
$ cat file 
product: Nike New Awesome Shoe
price: 123
color: black
```

```bsh
$ yq -y '.brand = (.product|split(" ")[0])' file
product: Nike New Awesome Shoe
price: 123
color: black
brand: Nike
```

Here, `yq` is the tool from the `python-yq` [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package on macOS or Linux, also available from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

The expression takes the `product` string and splits it on spaces.  The first of the resulting words is assigned to the key `brand`.

If you're using Mike Farah's `yq`, you'd instead do

```
$ yq '.brand = (.product|split(" ")|.[0])' file
product: Nike New Awesome Shoe
price: 123
color: black
brand: Nike
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r "s/(^product: ([^ ]+) .*)/\1\nbrand: \2/" shoe.lst
```

Similar to other solutions, but I use -r, to simplify the sed expressions: You can omit the backslash in front of parenthesis.

I match for at least one non blank.

\1...\2 is the outer expression, the whole line, like & used by others. This works from outer to inner parens and left to right, when counting for the nested expression.

And \n is just the newline, as known from many languages.

Answer (score -1):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '/^product:/{print $0; print "price:",$2; next;}1' file
```