# SED - Generate line only if match some words in OTHER LINE

Tags: linux, bash, sed, regular-expression

Assume I have 2 files in a folder

```
...
product: Nike New Awesome Running Shoe
price: 123
color: black
...
```

```
...
product: Nike New Awesome Salloon Soccer Shoe
price: 123
color: black
...
```

I need to accomplish bellow scenario **using single SED command**, in all files using *.txt

I need to search in (product:) line if it contains the string Salloon Soccer (this is an example, it could be another terms/strings).

The search MUST apply ONLY IN THE product: LINE

And ONLY if contains that string, create a new line with (venue: indoor)
The other file that do not contain the "search term" keeps intact.
Look bellow the 2 files result:

```
...
product: Nike New Awesome Running Shoe
price: 123
color: black
...
```

```
...
product: Nike New Awesome Salloon Soccer Shoe
venue: indoor
price: 123
color: black
...
```

Comment: @fuzzydrawrings here... can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the files are valid YAML files, using Andrey Kislyuk's `yq` (as I did in [my answer to your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697157/493832)):

```bsh
yq -y -i '
    if (.product | contains("Salloon Soccer")) then
        .venue = "indoor"
    else
        empty
    end' *.txt
```

This adds a `venue` field with the value `indoor` to each file that has a top-level `product` field that contains the string `Salloon Soccer`.  The change is made in-place due to the `-i` option.

Comment: Hey @they, can you help me with language here? 
I need use this for other thing now. How can i get a if with AND operator?
Like IF .product contains XXXX AND .price=123 then .newline = "'

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is include whatever you want to match in the expression. If you require the `product` line contain the string `*Salloon Soccer`, the matching expression is simply `/^product: .*Salloon Soccer.*/`:

```
sed 's/^product: .*Salloon Soccer.*/&\nvenue: indoor/' file.txt
```

See `man sed`.

Comment: `man sed` tells me that `\n` is undefined in the replacement string. It says if I want to add a newline I have to use an actual newline preceeded by a backslash.

Comment: @Philippos Thanks for sharing and for the downvote but the suggestion to look at `man sed` was for the OP who didn't seem to understand the pattern matching aspect. I realize the newline in the substitution isn't POSIX, but it apparently works for OP (who's also using `bash` - also not POSIX).

Comment: Using `bash` has nothing to do with being able to use `\n` as newline in the replacement part of the `s` command in `sed`.

Comment: You _could_ use the `a` command in `sed` to append the new contents to the line after any line matching your expression.

Comment: Please help me here @they https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71700427/using-yq-in-front-matter-md-files-with-conditional-operations